# Connect to FileMaker Database from Grails app

Tags: grails, jdbc, driver, connection-string, filemaker

I can't achieve to connect with a FileMaker database when I use the fmjdbc driver. I put the jar library in the /lib folder and I try connect with the next connection params:

```
dataSource {

    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.ddtek.jdbc.sequelink.SequeLinkDriver"
    username = "myUser"
    password = "myPass"
}
```

...

```
test {

      dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url ="jdbc:sequelink://myIP:2399;serverDataSource=mydataBase;user=myUser;password=myPass"
      }
}
```

Unfortunately, It return a ClassNotFoundException error:

```
"...
Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.ddtek.jdbc.sequelink.SequeLinkDriver'
...
```

"

I think It could be a unregister-dependency lack, as well as the runtime dependency of mysql driver placed at buildConfig.groovy file:

```
 dependencies {

      runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'

 }
```

I have seen the manifest.mf jar file but This don't have any relevant data. Here the content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_26-156 (Apple Inc.)
```

but I don't know how build the dependency string for com.ddtek.jdbc.sequelink.SequeLinkDriver driver..
Anybody says how could be it? Will It be the problem, or maybe coud be another?

Thanks a lot.
Luis.

Comment: try running the command grails compile --refresh-dependencies

Comment: try @allthenutsandbolts' suggestion. If it still doesn't work, do the usual grails clean -> refresh dependencies -> run-app

Comment: unfortunately this solution hasn't worked. Also, I'm a bit confused with jar lib filemaker code because all packages start with the 'com.filemaker' prefix and neither with the 'com.ddtek' prefix.

Comment: I've tried with dependency strings at runtime as well as  'jdbc:sequelink.SequeLinkDriver' , 'jdbc:jdbc.sequelink.SequeLinkDriver' or 'jdbc:com.ddtek.jdbc.sequelink.SequeLinkDriver' but Grails don't recognize them as valid dependency strings...
The FM tutorial has a Java example:
...
// register the JDBC client driver
try {
Driver d =
(Driver)Class.forName("com.ddtek.jdbc.sequelink.SequeLinkDriver").newInstance();
} catch(Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
...
but I don't know how to translate it to a valid Grails project config.
Thanks a lot for your response. Regards